# Usar un modal de confirmación en asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap

espero y me puedan echar una mano con este problemilla que no puedo resolver. 
Estoy realizando un proyecto en asp.net y dentro del gridview tengo un botón que realiza una acción de solicitar datos. Estoy usando un modal para la confirmación pero cuando doy click en el botón de solicitar me abre el modal y hace el submit sin darme la oportunidad de si quiero hacer esa acción o no. El modal lo hago con bootstrap y utilizo javascript. Espero y me puedan orientar.

Este es mi código del botón dentro del gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Solicitar" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAgregar" runat="server" Text="Solicitar" OnClick="btnGuardar_Click" OnClientClick="return show_confirm(event)" CssClass="btn btn-info solicitar" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Este es mi código del modal, sacado de bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancelar" Cssclass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Cancelar" data-dismiss="modal"  ></asp:Button>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirmar" Cssclass="btn btn-primary" Text="Confirmar"></asp:Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y por último un script js, perdonen si está todo mal hecho

```
script type="text/javascript">
    function show_confirm(event) {

            $(document).ready(function () {

                var ref = $("#exampleModal").modal();
                ref = false;
                return false;


            });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el modal no espera que el usuario pulse en Aceptar o Cancelar para devolver el valor al botón.

En este caso tal vez lo mejor sería que el botón btnAgregar no tuviera un OnClick, que sólo tenga el OnClientClick para mostrar el modal, y en el botón btnConfirmar del modal agregale el OnClick para que envíe la petición al servidor.

Sería algo así:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Solicitar" ItemStyle-Width="50">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAgregar" runat="server" Text="Solicitar"  OnClientClick="$('#exampleModal').modal()" CssClass="btn btn-info solicitar" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Y esto en el HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancelar" Cssclass="btn btn-secondary" Text="Cancelar" data-dismiss="modal" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirmar" Cssclass="btn btn-primary" Text="Confirmar" OnClick="btnGuardar_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, solo que creo que tendré un inconveniente, ya que había hecho algo similiar a lo que comentas, lo que sucede es que ese botón que solicita obtiene datos del gridview y los manda el método que realiza la acción, y si lo cambio por el de confirmar del modal creo que habría un problema porque no podría pasar esos datos del gridview, o al menos eso me sucedió cuanto intenté algo parecido.

Comment: Hola Sergio.
En ese caso podrías mover el modal para que quede dentro del TemplateField, así seguro te funciona.

Comment: Gustavo te agradezco de nuevo tu respuesta, intenté hacer lo que me dices pero me marca error, me dice que no puede estar dentro del templated field, pero si me deja meterlo dentro del item template donde tengo mi botón, crees que ahi funcionaria? o mejor lo meto dentro del gridview

Comment: Hola Sergio. A eso me refería, deberías ponerlo en el ItemTemplate del TemplateField, donde está tu botón. Después avisame dio te funcionó. Saludos.

Comment: Gustavo, no sé como agradecerte la ayuda que me has brindado, me funcionó tal cual me comentaste, de verdad que estoy muy agradecido. Solo una última consulta si no es molestia, estoy usando en el js el event.preventDefault() ya que si no lo utilizo la página hace como un tipo de submit y me regresa a otra parte, pero el problema es que tengo que hacer click dos veces en mi botón de consultar para que abra el modal, existe otra función o alguna manera de prevenir ese submit, de manera que solo baste con un click para abrir el modal?

Comment: El raro que funcione así, o sea, que tengas que pulsar dos veces el botón.  ¿Probaste con sacarle lo del preventDefault() y agregarle al final un "return false"?

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con [AJAX Control Toolkit](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=DevExpressPage&utm_campaign=AjaxControlToolkit&utm_content=AjaxControlToolkit_Blog_DevExpressPage) con el control [PopupControlExtender](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/PopupControl)